# Python Django миграции

Tags: python, django, миграция

Ошибка в миграциях, не могу открыть или добавлять что - либо
Exception Value:
no such column: main_articles.anons

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('тут типо текст', max_length=50, default=' не ввел текст ваще')
    anons = models.CharField("Тут типо анонс", max_length=250)
    full_text = models.TextField('Тут типо текст главный вот да')
    date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Новость'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Новости'
```

python manage.py migrate или makemigrations не помогли, python manage.py makemigrations main(main название приложения) тоже не помогло

Comment: Если это не продакшн и введенных данных нет, самое простое - удалить таблицы бд и файлы миграций, а затем заново попробовать makemigrations, затем migrate.